# what class is the .sendToAll() method found

Tags: java

I was following a material, about socket programming in java, and i encountered problem. My server object does not have a .sendToAll() method and .removeConnection() method. Please someone should point me in the right direction. Below is the code.

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
Server server;
Socket socket;

public ServerThread(Server server, Socket socket){
    this.server = server;
    this.socket = socket;

    //start the thread
    start();
}
public void run(){
    try{
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        while (true){
            String message = din.readUTF();

            System.out.println("Sendong "+ message);

            server.sendToAll(message);
        }
    }catch(EOFException x){

    }catch (IOException x){
        x.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        server.removeConnection(socket);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the class that you are using for the server.
Look at the package import for the class.

Then check the API for that server class to see if it defines the API calls you are trying to make.